# ClojureScript turn a Javascript Map Iterator into a seq

Tags: clojurescript, clojurescript-javascript-interop

I'm calling a Javascript library and getting a Map Iterator back (which in Javascript you use with for ... in)

How do I turn this into a ClojureScript sequence so I can call `for` on it?

Comment: Example code & output?

Comment: It's not a bug. I'm looking for an example of how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

By looking at the [MDN documentation on Map iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/@@iterator) you can check that you can navigate the iterator with the `.next()` method which will return a JS object with 2 properties: `value` and `done`, where `value` will contain an Array of size 2 with the key and value for each entry on the Map, and `done`, which will be false until the iterator is exhausted (no more entries).

Using this, we can create a ClojureScript function that takes the iterator and builds a Map (or a ClojureScript map if you remove the `clj->js`).

```clj
(defn ^:export iterToMap [iter]
  (loop [acc {}]
    (let [elem (.next iter)]
      (if (.-done elem) ;; no more elements
        (clj->js acc) ;; or just use `acc` for a regular CLJS map
        (let [[k v] (array-seq (.-value elem))]
          (recur (assoc acc k v)))))))
```

I used the `^:export` metadata flag so that you can call the function from the console. If you save this function in say `app/main.cljs`, the function will be available as `app.main.iterToMap()` in the global JS object.

You can use it as follows in the Developer Console:

```
> const map1 = new Map();
> map1.set("0", "zero");
> map1.set("1", "one");

// Now call the function, note that map1.entries() returns an Iterator:

> app.main.iterToMap(map1.entries());

// Returns:
Object { 0: "zero", 1: "one" }
```

If you want a sequence of key-value pairs, you can use the same principle to create a [lazy-sequence](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/lazy-seq), you just need to remember to hold a reference to the iterator so you can extract the next item.